# How to upload file to Google drive with Postman using multipart?

Tags: rest, file-upload, google-drive-api, postman, multipart

How could I upload file to Google Drive using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) with Postman?

I also want to set **file's name** and **parent directory**.

### What have I done:

I try to upload file with following properties:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I get 403 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "parseError",
                "message": "Parse Error"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Parse Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: The last comment on Seems that Postman is not able to send JSON body together with a multipart attached file suggests it can't be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved my problem, using answer on this question: **[How to send application/json data along with file in postman multipart/form-data post request?](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3331#issuecomment-375596157)**.

### Solution

1) create file for upload to Google Drive: `test.txt`;

2) create file `upload-options.json` with file's [metadata properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#request-body) in json format:

```
{
  "name": "my-uploaded-file.txt",
  "parents": ["<parent-directory-id>"]
}
```

3) add two `form-data` fields:

- **first** - `upload-options.json`
- **second** - `test.txt`

  [image]

Comment: I have tried the same way you posted above but I get the below error, I've also added the scopes required for my app in console.developers.google.com.

{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
                "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
    }
}

Comment: @Krrish this is probably because when getting your access token via OAuth, you didnt provide/request a big enough scope. Each/Most drive request require different scopes, they are always shown in the the references. For file.create this would be as shown here. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth

Comment: That's a nice approach, but unfortunately, doesn't work for me. Still saves the file as "Untitled" even in `upload-options.json` defined otherwise. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you should consider about permission scope of your app.
add line code below help you access full control of google driver api

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
```